# how to use a nested for loop to view/operate on executable files in sub-directories using bash?

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop, echo, nested-loops

I'm a noob at bash scripting, and I've been trying to iterate over the files in sub-directories of sub-directories and `cp` them over to a new directory.

First of all, below is what my file directory looks like:

```
songs/a/mac01/d001.mp3
            /d002.mp3

     a/mac02/d003.mp3
            /d004.mp3

     a/mac03/d005.mp3
            /d006.mp3
```

This is my code so far (current working directory is one level up from the `songs` directory:

```
for d1 in $(find -L ./songs -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d); do
    for d2 in $(find -L $d1 -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d); do
        for d3 in $(find -L $d2 -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d); do
            echo "$d3"
```

When I run the above code, I get the following output:

```
...
...
./songs/a/mac01
./songs/a/mac02
./songs/a/mac03
...
...
```

My ultimate goal is to `cp` each of those `.mp3` files to a different directory, but I have been just `echo`ing the files to see if the for loops are working properly.

But as you can see, even though I'm at the third for loop, the output shows only the third-level directories and not the contents therein.

The ideal output I want to see would like so:

```
...
...
./songs/a/mac01/d001.mp3
./songs/a/mac01/d002.mp3
./songs/a/mac02/d003.mp3
./songs/a/mac02/d004.mp3
./songs/a/mac03/d005.mp3
./songs/a/mac03/doo6.mp3
...
...
```

What am I doing wrong here?

I would really appreciate the help :)

Comment: One `find ... -exec cp ... \;`?

Comment: Just remove the `-type d` in the innermost `for` loop.

Comment: By the way, if `songs/` and all the `songs/a/` directories contain only directories, no other file types, you can also use
`for d1 in ./songs/*; do for d2 in "$d1"/*; do for d3 in "$d2"/*; do echo "$d3"; done; done; done`. The advantage of that would be that directories with special characters, like spaces, in their name are handled properly.

Comment: The shortest solution, however, is `for file in songs/*/*/*; do echo $file; done`